# Асинхронный код (Task.WaitAll) вешает программу

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Есть некоторое недопонимание с работой асинхронного кода, в связи с чем прошу помощи. Следующая функция вешает программу:

```
    private List<ContractsList> GetContractsDetail(contracts)
    {
        List<string> contractsList = new List<string>();    // Сюда буду ложить ответы
        Task[] requests = new Task[contracts.Length];    // Создаю массив для моих тасков

        Uri Uri = new Uri(Settings.CONTRACT_DETAIL_URI);    

        for (int i = 0; i < contracts.Length; i++)    // По каждому контракту
        {
            HttpRequest ContractRequest = new HttpRequest();    //Это мой класс для работы с HttpClient

            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["access_token"] = token, ["contract_id"] = contracts[i] };    // Данные для GET запроса
            requests[i] = ContractRequest.Get(Uri, data);    // Моя обертка над HttpClient.GetAsync
        }

        Task.WaitAll(requests);    // Тут зависает программа
        // Тут еще код, который я не дописал

        return contractsList;
    }
```

По информации в интернете не до конца понимаю:

1. работает ли `WaitAll` как `await`? И если да, то почему виснет
   программа?
2. стартуют ли вообще мои Таски?
3. в каком месте кода я не прав? =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. `Task.Wait`, `Task.WaitAll` - это совсем не `await`! `await` - это асинхронное продолжение, `Wait` же является синхронным ожиданием.

У вас взаимоблокировка. Вы работаете в потоке UI - а потому все ваши задачи свои продолжения ставят в очередь событий. Пока эта очередь не "провернется" - задача не будет выполнена. Но саму очередь вы при этом заблокировали синхронным ожиданием!

Правильный способ избавиться от взаимоблокировки - использовать асинхронный код на всех уровнях. Да, для этого саму функцию `GetContractsDetail` нужно тоже сделать асинхронной:

```
await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

Костыльный, но более простой способ - вынести задачи в пул потоков:

```
 requests[i] = Task.Run(() => ContractRequest.Get(Uri, data));
```

Еще один костыльный и простой способ - проставить `.ConfigureAwait(false)` на первом операторе `await` в методе `ContractRequest.Get`

Comment: Спасибо. Правильно ли я понял,  что `await Task.WhenAll(requests);` - сработает так-же, [еслиб я написал вот так](http://pastebin.com/dsDFd8mz). Ну, образно говоря.

Comment: @Олег да, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: Вы меня выручили)

Comment: Павел, можно еще один маленький вопрос? Допустим в данном примере я использовал `WhenAll()` следующим образом: `string[] resp = await Task.WhenAll(requests);`. Вопрос: Массив ответов `resp` будет заполняться элементами в том порядке, в котором хранятся запросы в `requests`? Или по мере завершения запросов?

Comment: В порядке массива `requests`

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и предполагал, но хотелось уверенности, так как в дальнейшем полагаюсь на этот порядок.

Answer (score 4):

`WaitAll` работает не так, как `await`.

- `WaitAll` блокирует текущий поток до завершения тасков.
- `await` освобождает текущий поток, и ставит остаток метода в continuation к таску в соответствующем контексте (GUI-потоке или потоке с тем же HttpContext).

Соответственно, если код внутри вашей обертки решит поставить таск на выполнение в текущем контексте (GUI или ASP.NET), то он будет ждать освобождения контекста. А `WaitAll` будет держать поток (и контекст), ожидая окончания выполнения кода - и все подвиснет.

Это достаточно подробно раскрыто в [MSDN Magazine, Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming / Async All the Way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Не стоит смешивать `async`/`await` и прямые `Wait`.

Comment: Спасибо, стало яснее.